# Completely Destroyed iPhone 6

Tags: iphone, damage

Just today, my iPhone 6 was left on the top of my friends car and I forgot to take it down. So when we drove, it flew off the top and got destroyed by another car. When I went to go pick it up, the entire screen came off and the entire body of my phone is destroyed. It hasn't yet been a year since I bought the iPhone with AT&T. Do you think I can get a replacement for the phone? any warranty benefits? Again, my phone is completely destroyed but the SIM AND BATTERY are perfectly fine. What should i do?

Comment: Can you post a picture? Just curious on how bad she is injured :)

Answer (score 1):

Warranty from Apple doesn't cover accidental damage.

If you have insurance from the carrier or AppleCare plus, they will pay some or all the costs to repair it.

Put the pieces in a ziplock bag and call Apple or visit a retail store to get a quote for replacement in writing so you can provide that to the carrier and/or insurance company. Depending on how badly you need a replacement, you might pay for Apple's repair and check coverage later.

Best of luck and have a look at cases like life proof and otter box that might help in bad situations if you decide not to insure the replacement.

Comment: and watch out for incoming traffic while picking up the pieces.

Comment: do you think (i know this is bad but just because im curious) if i told apple someone had deliberately threw my phone onto the road they would be lenient?

Comment: @Neha, I would say no, it is better to say it was an accident, fell out while you where riding a bike.

Answer (score 0):

$199 will get you a new iPhone 6 when you take it in to the Apple Store. So that's your worst-case scenario. Been there, done that (atop the car and all; I also washed mine on a different occasion.) Every time you pay the $199, you learn another way to be careful with your phone. But you'll walk out of the store able to use your (new) device!